# Shell script strings

Tags: string, shell

I actually grep for a line from a file and store that line as a string.
When I compare that string with a similar string (which is exactly same as other), I'm not getting the result as both of them being equal.

Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash

ref="BIP1295I: Integration node 'IB10NODEQ03' is an active multi-instance or High Availability integration node that is running on queue manager 'IB10QMGRQ03'."

message1=$(mqsilist| grep IB10NODEQ03 2>&1)

echo $message1
echo $ref

if [ "$message1" = "$ref" ]; then
echo "equal"
else
echo "not equal"
fi
```

### EXECUTING THE SCRIPT

```
[mqbrkrs@dclqsa80 /tmp]$ sh script*
BIP1295I: Integration node 'IB10NODEQ03' is an active multi-instance or High Availability integration node that is running on queue manager 'IB10QMGRQ03'.
BIP1295I: Integration node 'IB10NODEQ03' is an active multi-instance or High Availability integration node that is running on queue manager 'IB10QMGRQ03'.
not equal
```

Comment: Try `echo /$message1/ | cat -vet`. There may be trailing whitespace, or tabs somewhere.

Comment: Quote the expansions: `echo "$message1"; echo "$refand"` and check if they really are identical.

Comment: Hi Thanks both of you. There is a white space at the end of the line which I grepped.

Comment: So to match that line, I added a space at the end of my reference line also. Now both of them are equal.

Comment: As I have got my exact reference line, when something unexpected comes when I grep, that will fail. Only this will match.